# Php preg_replace numbers characters

Tags: php

```
$my_string = '88888805';
echo preg_replace("/(^.|.$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)/","*",$,my_string);
```

This shows the first and last number like thus 8******5
But how can i show this number like this 888888**. (The last 2 number is hidden)

Thank you!

```
From this: 8******5
To: 888888**
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have worked on this Regex pattern to do something unique. However, I will provide you with a general one that should fit your question without using your current pattern.

```
$my_string = '88888805';
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]+)[0-9]{2}$/","$1**",$,my_string);
```

**Explanation:**

The `([0-9]+)` will match all digits, this could be replaced with `\d+`, it's between brackets to be captured as we are going to use it in the results.

`[0-9]{2}` is going to match the last 2 digits, again, it can be replaced with `\d{2}`, it's outside the brackets because we don't want to include them in the result. the `$` after that is to indicate the end of the test, it's optional anyways.

**Results:**

```
Input: 88888805
Output: 888888**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace("/(.{2}$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(.)/","*",$my_string);
```

If it for a uni assignment, you'd probably want to do this. Basically says, don't match if its the last two characters, otherwise match.